# Function that will generate iter samples of size n from a gamma distribution with shape parameter alpha and rate parameter beta

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

The function needs to return the mean and standard deviation of each sample.

This is what I have:

```
sample_gamma <- function(alpha, beta, n, iter) {
  mean = alpha/beta
  var = alpha/(beta)^2
  sd = sqrt(var)
  gamma = rgamma(n,shape = alpha, scale = 1/beta)
  sample_gamma = data.frame(mean = replicate(n = iter, expr = mean))
}
```

I'm very lost for this. I also need to create a data frame for this function.

Thank you for your time.

Edit:

```
sample_gamma <- function(alpha, beta, n, iter) {
  output <- rgamma(iter, alpha, 1/beta)
  output_1 <- matrix(output, ncol = iter)
  means <- apply(output_1, 2, mean)
  sds <- apply(output_1, 2, sd)
mystats <- data.frame(means, sds)
return(mystats)
  }
```

This works except for the sds.  It's returning NAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want.  But say you want to create 10 samples of size 1000, alpha = 1, beta = 2.  Then you can create a single stream of rgamma realizations, dimension them into a matrix, then get your stats with apply, and finally create a data frame with those vectors:

```
output <- rgamma(10*1000, 1, 1/2)
output <- matrix(output, ncol = 10)
means <- apply(output, 2, mean)
sds <- apply(output, 2, sd)
mystats <- data.frame(means, sds)
```

You could wrap your function around that code, replacing the hard values with parameters.

Comment: Almost.  The only thing that doesn't work is the sds.  It's coming up all NA's.

Comment: I used a more general case. See my edited code above.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.